# @AfterClass not working in cucumber scripts

Tags: java, selenium, automation

@Before and @After is working in my cucumber script. but **@AfterClass** is not working
i have imported **junuit.AfterClass** package

```
@AfterClass 
public void close()
{
driver.quit()
System.out.Println("hello");
}
```

Comment: AfterClass and BeforeClass methods need to be static...

Comment: i tried with static ...still it doesnot work.. even though there is no error still it  doesnot execute

Comment: Are you using Cucumber.class runner? The before and after annotations which are running are they from the junit or cucumber?

Comment: @Grasshopper cucumber

Answer (score 2):

JUnit/TestNG hooks do not appear to work with Cucumber step definition classes. I have tried both. The test did not fail but the `@AfterClass` method did not execute.

Cucumber has [Tagged Hooks](https://zsoltfabok.com/blog/2012/09/cucumber-jvm-hooks/). They allow you to specify when to run `@Before` or `@After` methods based on the tags in your feature file.

```
// Feature file
@internal @login
Scenario Outline: Log in with valid username
    Given I am at the Login page
    When I log in with valid Username and Password: <username> <password>
    When I click Submit
    Then I should see the message: <message>


// Step definition class
import cucumber.api.java.After;

@Given
@When
@When
@Then

@After("@login")
public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
}
```

To use multiple tags, you can do `@After("@internal,@login")`.